# Phpunit mock has no effect

Tags: php, phpunit

code:

```
class MockMe
{
    public function mockMeee()
    {
        return 'Im not mocked';
    }
}
```

test:

```
$sut = new MockMe();
$this
    ->getMock(get_class($sut))
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('mockMeee')
   ->will($this->returnValue('Im finally mocked'));
echo $sut->mockMeee();
```

this outputs the original `"Im not mocked"`, but it supposed to send the `Im finally mocked` text. What is wrong?

EDIT: done:

```
$stub = $this->getMock('MockMe');
$stub->method('mockMeee')->willReturn('Im finally mocked');
echo $stub->mockMeee();
```

Comment: Just worth mentioning; you should still be able to use `->will($this->returnValue())` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constructing the real MockMe, then building a mock that you are doing nothing with. I think your test should be something like:

```
$sut = $this->getMock('MockMe');

$sut->expects($this->any())
    ->method('mockMeee')
    ->will($this->returnValue('Im finally mocked'));

echo $sut->mockMeee();
```

Refer to http://phpunit.de/manual/4.2/en/test-doubles.html for more information on PHPUnit mocks.

Comment: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker::mockMeee() at where the echo is

Comment: You probably need to require/include the class you want to test. Can you include the full test file in your sample? The point is, that your call to getMock will return you the mock object. You then need to call methods on this object.

Comment: if I had not included that file, the example wouldnt even have worked either

Comment: True. My mistake. Are you using Namespaces?

Comment: Maybe var_dump the mock object once you have built it. Perhaps it will give you an idea.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.